# E: Unable to lock the administration directory

Tags: 15.04

After trying somefixes I still get the error:

```
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/) is another process using it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/unable-to-lock-the-administration-directory-var-lib-dpkg-is-another-process)

Comment: Please add some more information, because without it, it will be very difficult to help you. What do you mean by "some fixes"? Which command do you run to get this error message?

Answer (score 0):

Enter terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run

```
sudo killall dpkg
```

There are a few programs that may be using it, try to discover them and post an edit. And more, you said *After trying all of these fixes*, but which fixes? Please be more specific, if you are refering to another question post its link here.